KMM with Compose Multiplatform UI framework- error while rebuilding project
When I try to rebuild my project in KMM in Android Studio (Android Studio Hedgehog | 2023.1.1 Patch 2), I got this error:
Attachments:
causeThrowable
java.lang.NullPointerException
at androidx.compose.compiler.plugins.kotlin.k1.AnnotationUtilsKt$makeComposableAnnotation$1.getType(AnnotationUtils.kt:38)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.descriptorUtil.DescriptorUtilsKt.getAnnotationClass(DescriptorUtils.kt:402)
and more...

The affected file is MyApp.kt in iOS part of the project, which looks like this:
package com.radekstuj.myapp.presentation

import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.window.ComposeUIViewController
import com.radekstuj.myapp.data.model.DriverFactory
import com.radekstuj.myapp.presentation.AppViewModel
import com.radekstuj.myapp.presentation.MyApp
import platform.UIKit.UIViewController

fun MainViewController(): UIViewController {
    val driver = DriverFactory().createDriver()
    val viewModel = AppViewModel(driver)
    return ComposeUIViewController {
        MyApp(viewModel)
    }
}

I am also using these dependencies and libraries:
compose = "1.6.2"
compose-plugin = "1.6.0"
junit = "4.13.2"
kotlin = "1.9.22"

ktor = "2.3.2"
serialization = "1.6.2"
coroutines = "1.8.1-Beta"
napier = "2.6.1"
sqldelight = "2.0.1"

I am using Compose Multiplatform, so I can share UI written in kotlin for both platforms.
The android app is working (I can launch it), but I need to rebuild the project so the changes will be applied to the iOS part too.
I tried to search over the internet but found nothing, then I tried to change versions of dependencies above and the result is the same. Also this error occurred after I added the SQLDelight dependency (and other necessities).
The only thing somehow close was this: text but the suggestion was to upgrade coroutines to version 1.8.1-Beta, which I did and still got the same result when trying to rebuild project.
I also tried to start from new project and implement everything again, but it didn't work.

minimal reproducible example would be helpful here
